# OpenSCAD keeps crashing when I raise my precision past $fn=29?

Tags: windows-8, crash, cad, openscad

OpenSCAD stopped working for me on designs that previously rendered fine. After testing I found out that any precision greater than `$fn=29` causes the program to crash with an error message reading `openscad.exe has stopped working`. I am need to print parts with precision of at least `$fn>100`.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program several times and haven't been able to fix the problem. I have watched the CPU during the calculations and it never reaches more than 35%.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this problem? I also have not changed computers or even the code. Thanks!

I am using Windows 32 bit, Version 2013.06. The default version.

Comment: I've been getting this too. Exactly same symptoms.

Comment: Here is the issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/428 OpenSCAD is unusable in Windows 8 right now, so I'm using it in Linux as a workaround. The $fn threshold that causes a crash seems to vary with model complexity. The problem started for me after updating to Windows 8.1 (x64).